# Sum over all complement of prime ideals generate the ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring, and for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, pick $t_{\mathfrak{p}} \in A \setminus \mathfrak{p}$. Does $A = \sum_{\mathfrak{p}}t_{\mathfrak{p}}A$ hold for any choice of $t_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

This is from the first line of p.233 of Matsumura. If one of $t_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is unit, then it is trivial, but I don't know how to show it when all $t_{\mathfrak{p}}$ are not unit. How can we generate a unit using $t_{\mathfrak{p}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal $\sum_{\mathfrak{p}}t_{\mathfrak{p}}A$ is, by construction, not contained in any prime ideal (since $t_\mathfrak{p}\not\in \mathfrak{p}$ for each $\mathfrak{p}$).  In particular, it is not contained in any maximal ideal, which means it must be all of $A$.

Comment: Wow, you right. Thank you very much!